# Recursive fetch in CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a data structure simplified to this:

[image: Data Structure]

So a folder can contain multiple folders or snippets and each snippet is part of a folder.
I want to fetch all Snippets which are in a given folder or which are in a folder which is a children of a specific folder.

The first case works for me, but I have problems getting the second case right.

To make this more clear here is an example:

[image: Example]

When I select Folder C I'd like to get Snippet 3 but when I select Folder B or Folder A I'd like to get Snippet 1, Snippet 2 and Snippet 3.

This is what I currently have:

```
class Store {
...
    func snippetsFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Snippet> {
        let fetch: NSFetchRequest<Snippet> = Snippet.fetchRequest()
        fetch.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        fetch.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = ["folder", "tags"]
        fetch.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "updateDate", ascending: false)]
        return fetch
    }
...
}


let context = PersistenceManager.shared.mainContext
let store = SnippetStore(context: context)
fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: store.snippetsFetchRequest(),
        managedObjectContext: context,
        sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
        cacheName: nil)
fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "folder == %@", selectedFolder)
do {
    try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
} catch {
    ...
}
```

But this does only fetch the snippets which are direct children of the given/selected folder.

Is there any way I can solve my problem by still using `NSFetchedResultsController`?

Comment: This looks a bit like the Composite design pattern, you could solve this in code by having a method `allSnippets` that gets `snippets` and merges that with the result of calling `allSnippets` on all of the `children`

Comment: Yes, I thought so too. I guess I could solve it by fetching all snippets and then applying some filter logic, respectively traversing the children. However I was asking myself whether there is some built-in functionality with NSPredicates. NSFetchedResultsController or by updating the underlying model architecture which I could use instead of removing my FetchedResultsController and implementing the logic by myself.

Comment: I see now that I forgot to say that `allSnippets` should be a method in the `Folder` class.

Comment: Sure, I already have a snippets relationship on the folders which I could leverage. I guess if there is no clever way by expressing this kind of FetchRequest this will be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You data structor is wrong.  People tend to think about data structor as have a "correct" form for the given information; that you want to "model" the reality as close as possible. This is false. Your model only has value to the extent that it give you value for your particular application.

In this case, if you want to fetch all decedents of a folder it would be best to make a relationship to represent that. You can make a many-to-many relationship of decedents and ancestors that you can set whenever you add an object. If you need more properties for filtering or ordering you should add them, even if those properties can in theory be derived from the current tree model. Just make sure to keep them all in sync.